# Iterating inventory hostnames shows mixed up hosts

Tags: ansible

Inventory

```
[servers]
host1 ansible_ssh_host=xxx
host2 ansible_ssh_host=xxx
```

Playbook

```
- name: Setup
  hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: ansible
  become: true
  roles:
  - task
```

Role task

```
- name: Show all the hosts in the inventory
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'all') }}"
```

Running playbook, inventory hosts are mixed up:

```
TASK [task : Show all the hosts in the inventory] ***************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=host1) => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host2] => (item=host1) => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host1] => (item=host2) => {
    "msg": "host2"
}
ok: [host2] => (item=host2) => {
    "msg": "host2"
}
```

Then I tried to run the following task, on hundreds of remote servers I added in inventory file, to change a user's password in a WordPress site:

```
- name: Update admin user's password
  command: wp user update admin
           --user_pass="{{ wp_admin_pwd }}"
  args:
      chdir: "/var/www/{{ item }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: www-data
  with_items: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'all') }}"
```

but hundreds of errors showed up:

```
failed: [host1] (item=host2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "cmd": "delta": null, "end": null, "item": "host2",
"msg": "Unable to change directory before execution: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/var/www/host2'"
```

In order to be able to update user's password with wp-cli tool, the wp command must be run in site's webroot folder, but it seems the loop I'm using is not the proper way to handle this.

Comment: whenever you find yourself writing a loop to go other a list of hosts in the inventory, this should raise a red flag. Although there can be a few exceptions, the hosts are generally looped through the natural play loop, not in a loop in a task. See Bastian answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is run on every host in the `servers` group.
With two servers this means that the task is executed four times (twice on every server).

```
TASK [task : Show all the hosts in the inventory] ***************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=host1) => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host2] => (item=host1) => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host1] => (item=host2) => {
    "msg": "host2"
}
ok: [host2] => (item=host2) => {
    "msg": "host2"
}
```

The task is run on `host1` twice. The first time with item `host1` and the second time with item `host2`.

Your playbook fails on `host1` because the second time the task is run there it gets the input `host2` and there is no `/var/www/host2` on `host1`.

You don't need a loop here. You want to run a single task on each `server`:

```
- name: Update admin user's password
  command: wp user update admin
           --user_pass="{{ wp_admin_pwd }}"
  args:
      chdir: "/var/www/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: www-data
```